# Refactoring details in TDD

Tags: unit-testing, refactoring, tdd

I have read this article

http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2011/10/06/avoid-testing-implementation-details-test-behaviours/

And I am confusing about

> "Code developed in the context of refactoring does not require new
>   tests!"

For example during refactoring I deside to move some calculation to a new class, which calculate for me factorial and I use this class to calculate some user specific details. In my requirements I will never have feature to write this class, it just created during refactoring. But when I should cover this class with tests to guarantee expected behaviour? As I understood I will never cover this class with tests or I an wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct.

There are two ways to consider refactoring, which cover two slightly different sets of techniques.

The first one is to do idempotent changes: fixing a little thing inside a method, so that the end-result is not changed. This, as said in the article, does not require change.

The second (much more interesting IMO) involves creating new classes, changing design patterns used, and sometimes doing huge changes to a class (or classes) structure. This **does require updating the tests as you go along**.

Let me propose a different interpretation: to me, you need at least two levels of testing:

- **Unit-tests**, for method testing. These tests will change when refactoring the production code, to follow the codes modification (they can even be done before the change, to drive it using TDD)
- **Acceptance tests** (possibly using an integration testing framework like `FITnesse` or `JBehave`, or plain JUnit if not) - these tests are high-level criteria for acceptance, they should **not** change during the refactoring, and still pass at the end of it. In fact, they are your harness, your *proof* for successful refactoring. Hack away at the code, modify it without thinking, and at the end of the day, your acceptance test(s) should still pass. If they do, you're good to go. If not, that means you've broken something (or your test was wrong in the first place).

(There is another level of testing that's needed: system tests, or integration tests, but they are beyond the scope of this question)

Comment: I believe that for proper TDD I should write small / fast tests. And very often run them. But I think acceptence test is not so fast and bunch of acceptence test for web site will be very slow. I think that changes in unit tests inevitable during refactoring. I didn't read TDD from Kent Beck so I have pure vision about that

Comment: So now I've read the article you've linked (I only quickly browsed it the first time) and the approach chosen by the writer is not to have fine-grain uniot-tests, but basically, only acceptance-tests. I'm a bit unconfortable with this approach myself, I prefer to change my tests during refactoring (especially because I rely heavily on mocking) - changing tests could be seen as part of the refactoring.

Comment: You're right, acceptance tests take more time to write, but they're invaluable to document your system and directly translate user requirements into actual code. In fact, my personal approach for TDD is: write acceptance test(s), validate it with the users, then start unit-TDD (basic red-green-refactor cycle), and finally check my acceptance test(s) pass. Sort of two nested TDD cycle in one, if you prefer :) And my original acceptance test(s) give me a nice way to know I completed the story/task I'm working on. Also nice when you have to hand over the task to someone else before it's complete.